# Nice and short sql query for ‘one-year-one-column’ table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, where-clause

I have one table that contains data for several years, example is here:

| year | value | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 101 | apples |
| 2021 | 102 | bananas |
| 2021 | 103 | pears |
| 2021 | 104 | raspberries |
| 2021 | 105 | strawberries |
| 2022 | 201 | apples |
| 2022 | 202 | bananas |
| 2022 | 203 | pears |
| 2022 | 204 | raspberries |
| 2022 | 205 | strawberries |
| 2023 | 301 | apples |
| 2023 | 302 | bananas |
| 2023 | 303 | pears |
| 2023 | 304 | raspberries |
| 2023 | 305 | strawberries |
| 2024 | 401 | apples |
| 2024 | 402 | bananas |
| 2024 | 403 | pears |
| 2024 | 404 | raspberries |
| 2024 | 405 | strawberries |

I need a one-year-one-column table like the following:

| 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 201 | 301 | 401 | apples |
| 102 | 202 | 302 | 402 | bananas |
| 103 | 203 | 303 | 403 | pears |
| 104 | 204 | 304 | 404 | raspberries |
| 105 | 205 | 305 | 405 | strawberries |

I use as many JOINs and WHEREs as many years I want in the output table, like this:

```
SELECT fruits21.value as '2021'
    , fruits22.value as '2022'
    , fruits23.value as '2023'
    , fruits24.value as '2024'
    , fruits21.fruit

FROM fruits as fruits21
JOIN fruits as fruits22 ON fruits22.fruit = fruits21.fruit
JOIN fruits as fruits23 ON fruits23.fruit = fruits21.fruit
JOIN fruits as fruits24 ON fruits24.fruit = fruits21.fruit

WHERE fruits21.year = 2021
    AND fruits22.year = 2022
    AND fruits23.year = 2023
    AND fruits24.year = 2024
```

Is there any other nice and short sql query to get the output table without using many JOINs and WHEREs (because there can be 100 years...)?

The answer 'No, there is no such a way' is sad but welcome anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use PIVOT, But You need to add year.

```
select * from (
  select year, value, fruit from fruit
) m
pivot
(
  avg(value)
  for year in ([2021], [2022], [2023])
) as pvt
```

Comment: Sqlite does not have a `pivot` function

Comment: oops didn't see that tag...